# Multiple commands produce error when doing deliver init

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fastlane

I am using `deliver` to submit application to review using fastlane...

I am getting next error:

> Multiple commands produce
>   '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fastlane-integration-ios-fhihcydqlflwnvfrgoyqgikqaugq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/fastlane-integration-ios.app/phone_number.txt':
>   1) Target 'fastlane-integration-ios' (project
>   'fastlane-integration-ios') has copy command from
>   '/Users/admin/Projects/fastlane-integration-ios/fastlane/metadata/review_information/phone_number.txt'
>   to
>   '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fastlane-integration-ios-fhihcydqlflwnvfrgoyqgikqaugq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/fastlane-integration-ios.app/phone_number.txt'
>   2) Target 'fastlane-integration-ios' (project
>   'fastlane-integration-ios') has copy command from
>   '/Users/admin/Projects/fastlane-integration-ios/fastlane/metadata/trade_representative_contact_information/phone_number.txt'
>   to
>   '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fastlane-integration-ios-fhihcydqlflwnvfrgoyqgikqaugq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/fastlane-integration-ios.app/phone_number.txt'

This is because some files have the same name and they are added all to build phases in compile bundle resources section.

How you solve this? I mean the folder structure and all depends on `deliver init` command, and I guess its not possible to just rename those conflicting files.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: you can rename all file

Comment: @AMITMONDOL and for example if I rename a file last_name.txt to blabla.txt, how iTunesConnect will know to fetch lastName from blabla.txt file?

Answer (score 7):

for me, my build phase -> copy bundle resources(pink area)   was referring the file multiple times.

after I removed those files (in pink area), I can build without error.

click your project [image]

Comment: Thx this was the solution!

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: My case was duplicated file in Extension in the pink area. Just removed the same name and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to delete the files with the same name that you've added to `Project` >`Build Phase` > `Copy Bundle Resources` block.

Then rename these resource files with Finder to have unique name, and finally re-add them in Xcode under `Copy Bundle Resources`. This way you won't break the references in Xcode to your text resource files.

If you're parsing these files in code, you should update the filename paths in code, too.

**Another idea:**

If the files having the same name (like `phone_number.txt`) are holding just phone numbers in the same format, you can add a new `Run Script Phase` to your `Build Phase` and implement a shell script that merges the content of the files having the same name, and then copies the resulting file to your app's Bundle.